# How to create separate lists if multiple strings are passed into a method?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a `list<String>` in my constructor method. I want to account for the possibility of multiple words being entered. For example, someone could pass in "bike" and that would be searched, or "Sally" and that would be searched. However, what I'd like to know is if there is a way to create separate streams of lists for all those words. Like if the method gets called multiple times, I want that word to loop through a text file and find the frequency of it, and have it in its own list. Same with the others. 
This way I can determine proximity of certain words in a text document in relation to other words. Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Would be helpful if you post what you have done here for a concrete example.

Comment: I *think* I know what you're asking, but I don't want to risk wasting time typing out an answer until you add a little bit more information about what you're actually trying to do and what state your software is in. That said, assuming my guess about what you're doing is correct, consider instead implementing something like `public SearchResult search (String text) { ... }`, returning the results for that specific word, and calling it multiple times rather than passing in lists of search terms to some constructor somewhere and trying to get the results back elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you!
This is in Java, done in eclipse.
What I am aiming to do is find the shortest distance between words in an essay. I want to create a method that when provided with word(s) will return the closest section of those words.
Example target words "Bob Sally Vermont" and sentences::

"Sally sees Bob in Vermont" , 
"Bob and Sally Vermont" ,
"Vermont Bob Sally"

....So the last one has the closest grouping of those words. That's the information I am looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately there are quite a few things in your question that don't make sense or are ambiguous. "I have a list<String> in my constructor method": is it an argument to the method or a variable within it? "I want to account for the possibility of multiple words being entered": lists have multiple strings, why doesn't that allow multiple words? "separate streams of lists": do you mean `Stream<List<String>>` or something else? "if the method gets called multiple times": if you are referring to the constructor, you can only call it once. "I want that word to loop through a text file": ??

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'll clarify. List<String> is an argument in the constructor method. I wasn't entirely sure about Lists and how they work, rather new to them. I didn't mean Stream<List<String>>, what I want to do is have multiple strings passed into the constructor once and then store each one of those strings individually, and then run each one against the essay and therefore I'd need to store each one into their own individual ArrayList.

Comment: At the end, I want to compare each of those individual ArrayLists and their indices and see which section of the essay contains the shortest distance with all those keywords in it.

Comment: [MCVE] would make the question much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, consider using a `Map`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class WordInAssay {

    Map<String,List<Integer>>  wordsMap;

    public WordInAssay(List<String> words) {

        //check that word is not null

        for(String word : words) {

            //map each word to a list. later store indices in that list.
            //using map will also eliminate identical words, if entered
            wordsMap.put(word, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }

        search();
    }

    private void search() {

        //use populated map to do the work you want. 
    }
}
```

Don't hesitate to ask for clarifications as needed.